# single-sided amplitude spectrum analysis

Tags: matlab, fft, spectrum

I need to check the quality of the EEG signal, to see if there is any noise in the signal (e.g. the 50 Hz line noise).
For what I have read so far, a good way to check would be to conduct Single-sided amplitude spectrum analyses both for all electrodes and for single electrodes (e.g. Cz).

I have run the following code:

```
 %Open the file
 FileName = 'Data.dat';
 fid = fopen(FileName);
 if fid < 0, error('Cannot open file'); end
 signal = fread(fid, Inf, 'float32');
 fclose(fid);

 %Set the parameters of the recording
 Fs = 1000; % Sampling frequency
 T = 1/Fs; % Sample time
 L = length(signal); % Length of signal

 %Amplitude spectrum analysis
 NFFT = 2^(nextpow2(L)-1);

 x=zeros(NFFT,1);
 x(1:NFFT,1) = signal(1:NFFT,1);

 YY = fft(x,NFFT)/L;
 ff = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
 %is taking the positive half of the spectrum (NFFT/2 +1 gives this, including 0 and nyquist, hence the +1) and mapping it onto your real frequencies from 'normalised frequency'.

 % Plot single-sided amplitude spectrum.
 figure; plot(ff,2*abs(YY(1:NFFT/2+1))), title('Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of tp'), xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'), ylabel('|Y(f)|');
```

I am not sure how to plot only one channel (e.g. Cz being channel 28).

(I have 64 channels, with 10-20 IS).

Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing that `signal` is a matrix, and on one line you set x equal to part of `signal`. `x() = signal(1:NFFT,1);`  If my guess is correct, you are plotting channel 1 right now, and you can select other channels by changing the second number.

Comment: @Trogdor `signal` is 62617120x1 double. So, I cannot change `1` in `signal(1:NFFT, 1)`; if I do so an error occurs: `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`